# To kill a CMD session

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I use a batch file to countdown and need to stop this countdown process in another batch file.

- I've tried to use these, but they all failed:

  ```cmd
  taskkill /f /fi "windowtitle eq countdown"
  taskkill /f /im countdown.cmd
  taskkill /f /fi "windowtitle eq counting down"
  ```
- `countdown.cmd`:

  ```cmd
  Title %~n0
  color 4F

  @echo off
  mode 32,10

  title Timer

  echo Enter time to countdown from.
  set time=233

  :loop
  cls

  set /a time=%time%-1
  if %time%==0 goto timesup

  title Counting down...

  echo.
  echo.

  echo.
  echo Countdown - [%time%]

  ping localhost -n 2 > nul
  goto loop

  :timesup
  echo Time is Up!
  start %~dp0FocusApp.cmd
  goto end

  :end
  @exit
  ```

Comment: What error messages do you get when trying the commands? Do you get any, or does it just not work?

Comment: "No tasks running with the specified critera"

Comment: "error: The process "countdown.cmd" not found."

Comment: Judging from the picture and the code, the WindowTitle is `Administrator:  countdown` respectively `Administrator:  Counting down...`, not `countdown`, and the Image is `cmd.exe`, not `countdown.cmd` . Better find the PID with `tasklist /v | find "Counting down..." with a `for /f "tokens=2"` loop and then `taskkill /PID`

Comment: Hi I am able to find the PID in separate command but when putting them together like this but shows error. Please help to rectify this script :  FOR /f "token=2 %%i in (tasklist /v | find "Counting down...") do taskkill /pid %%i

Comment: `...in ('tasklist /v ^| find "Counting down..."') do ...`

Comment: (btw:  if you mention `@Stephan`, I get a notification. I just happened to revisit this question by chance)

Comment: @Stephan Thanks. It works now.

Answer (score 2):

Place a `*` at the end of `windowtitle` for Windows to append something to the Window Title at process start:

```
taskkill /f /fi "windowtitle eq countdown*"
```